# Is there's a tool that can send raw bytes over the network for Windows?

Tags: windows, networking

Is there's a tool that I can use to send raw bytes to the NIC, for example sending the following bytes:

```
00 1e 8c ba c8 6e 2c d0 5a d8 47 8c 08 00 45 00 00 30 0d 07 40 00 80 06 55 d0 c0 a8 01 76 ad c2 28 10 e5 a6 00 50 85 84 81 b6 00 00 00 00 70 02 20 00 dd fc 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 01 04 02
```

or does Windows not support or have limited support for Raw Sockets?

Comment: You can write one in about 30 minutes.

Comment: Look at WinPcap: http://www.winpcap.org/

Answer (score 0):

Raw sockets can only be used prior to Windows XP SP1, the rest of Windows versions have limitations (e.g. you can't specify an invalid source IP address).
Either use Linux or Windows Server.